# Replace a block of spaces with a comma

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression, csv

I have a file in `txt` format that I want to convert to `csv`. Between each field there are blocks of spaces. The amount of spaces is not the same between every field.

Is there a command with sed or awk to replace the blocks with 3 spaces or more with an `,`. If there are only 2 spaces, it need to be ignored to avoid double spaces in the data to get replaced with `,`

Input:

```
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           A_PRIORADDRESS2_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 A_MONTHLYRENT_           A_EMPLOYEEID_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         A_REFDETAIL_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     A_VERBALPLEDGE                                                            
input  example,input2 example
```

output:

```
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE
input  example,input2 example
```

I can't find how to do this on the internet. I'm sure someone here can help me

Comment: you output is not a right CSV, because you should have commas also for empty fields: input  example,input2 example,,,,,,

Comment: also the input is not a CSV, because you have different fields separators: 3 or more space in the header and commas in the body. Or the first field is "input  example,input2 example"?

Comment: Have you seen [Convert a fixed-width file to CSV and remove trailing space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743619/convert-a-fixed-width-file-to-csv-and-remove-trailing-space)?

Comment: Is `input  example,input2 example` supposed to be one field or 2 fields?

Comment: Do you ever want to modify any other line than the 1st line of the input?

Comment: @EdMorton One field

Comment: @Kusalananda All lines

Comment: It's unfortunate that the example only shows modifications to the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -F' {3,}' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1} 1' file
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID_,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE,
input  example,input2 example
```

or with any awk hard-code 3 blanks then a `+` for the FS:

```
awk -F'   +' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1} 1' file
```

and if you want a valid CSV output (same number of fields on every line), assuming the first line contains all fields:

```
$ awk -F',| {3,}' -v OFS=',' 'NR==1{nf=NF} {$nf=$nf} 1' file
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID_,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE,
input  example,input2 example,,,,,,
```

or:

```
$ awk -F' {3,}' -v OFS=',' 'NR==1{nf=NF} {for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) $i="\"" $i "\""} 1' file
"A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_","A_PRIORADDRESS2_","A_MONTHLYRENT_","A_EMPLOYEEID_","A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_","A_REFDETAIL_","A_VERBALPLEDGE",""
"input  example,input2 example","","","","","","",""
```

depending on whether existing `,`s in the input are supposed to be treated as a field separator or not.

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
sed -E 's/[[:space:]]{3,}/,/g' file
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/\s{3,}/,/g' file
```

Comment: the output is not a right CSV, the user asks for a CSV: in the second row you do not have the field separators for the empty fields

Answer (score 3):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g/ \s ** 3..* /,/;'  file
```

The Raku code above is similar to the Perl answer with as slight change in syntax, due to the fact that Raku enumerates repeated instances of a character (or character class) using the `** min..max` notation. This allows `{}` curly-braces to be reserved for executable code within the regex (useful for things like running a counter variable, etc.).

Sample Input:

```
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           A_PRIORADDRESS2_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 A_MONTHLYRENT_           A_EMPLOYEEID_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         A_REFDETAIL_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     A_VERBALPLEDGE                                                            
input  example,input2 example
```

Sample Output:

```
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID_,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE,
input  example,input2 example
```

---

For anything other than a 'simple-CSV' format you'd probably want to `> ./tmp` redirect the output to a `tmp` file, then use Raku's `Text::CSV` module to parse the file.

Below, creating a `TSV` file from a `CSV` file (note columnar output with internal whitespace is properly double-quoted):

```
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN, sep => ",", strict => True);  csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT, sep => "\t");'  tmp
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_  A_PRIORADDRESS2_    A_MONTHLYRENT_  A_EMPLOYEEID_   A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_    A_REFDETAIL_    A_VERBALPLEDGE  
"input  example"    "input2 example"
```

For the final code example (immediately above), drop the `sep => "\t"` parameter and the code will use a `,` comma by default, giving you a `CSV` file.

*Using the parameter `strict => True` will throw an error if the number of colums is inconsistent from row-to-row.*

https://raku.land/github:Tux/Text::CSV
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Comment: this output is not a right CSV, the user asks for a CSV: in the second row you do not have the field separators for the empty fields

Comment: @aborruso I make it clear in the text that the first code block produces a `CSV` file, while the second code block produces a `TSV` file. Drop the `sep => "\t"` parameter from the second code block and the code will use a `,` comma by default.

Comment: The problem is not the separator. I think that your CSV output is wrong, because you must have the same number of separators in the heading and in the body, instead in your output you have seven commas in the header and one in the second rows.  CSV is a rectangular format https://i.imgur.com/C4RMn74.png

Comment: @aborruso I see now. Yes the OP posted data with a variable number of columns. It should be invariant. So the OP's terminology is deficient I would think.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from your [sample file](https://gist.github.com/aborruso/13e6c9a1de4ea69e19c2bcb4c6c7838f), you can use [Miller 6](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/installing-miller/) and run

```
mlr --ifs-regex "   +" --csvlite --ragged cat input.txt
```

to get

```
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID_,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE,
input  example,input2 example,,,,,,,
```

Some notes:

- using `--ifs-regex "   +"` you set 3 or more space as field separator;
- `ragged`, if a data line has fewer fields than the header line, fill remaining keys with empty string. If a data line has more fields than the header line, use integer field labels as in the implicit-header case

If you want remove the last empty field

```
mlr -N --ifs-regex "   +" --csvlite --ragged remove-empty-columns input.txt
```

If in row 2 the `,` is a field separator first you should standardize everything - to have the same separators - and pass the output to Miller

```
sed -r 's/,/   /g' input.txt | mlr -N --ifs-regex "   +" --icsvlite --ocsv --ragged remove-empty-columns
```

The output is a correct csv with the right amount of field separators

```
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID_,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE
input  example,input2 example,,,,,
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really only want to correct the header, you can replace all runs of space-like characters on the 1st line with commas:

```bash
$ sed '1s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/,/g' file
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID_,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE,
input  example,input2 example
```

To also remove that trailing comma that may not be needed:

```bash
$ sed -e '1s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/,/g' -e '1s/,$//' file
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID_,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE
input  example,input2 example
```

These `sed` commands only modify the header line of the input data, which is assumed to be the first line of input.  The remaining data is left unchanged.

---

An almost literal translation of that last `sed` command into `awk` would look like this:

```bash
$ awk 'NR == 1 { gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, ","); sub(/,$/, "") }; 1' file
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID_,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE
input  example,input2 example
```

... but it could be shortened into the following, where we let `awk` re-format the first line into a comma-delimited record by splitting it on runs of whitespace characters:

```bash
$ awk -v OFS=, 'NR == 1 { $1=$1 }; 1' file
A_DRIVERLICENSENUMBER_,A_PRIORADDRESS2_,A_MONTHLYRENT_,A_EMPLOYEEID_,A_WORKPHONESPECIALINSTR_,A_REFDETAIL_,A_VERBALPLEDGE
input  example,input2 example
```

In both instances, we avoid modifying any other input line than the 1st.